# How to embed mp3 into .exe file & Play it?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-mobile, audio, mp3

I am used to embed WAV into .exe and Play it using `PlaySound()`. However, using this method causes the .exe to become pretty big.

Is it possible to do the same with MP3 files and how to do it?

I have taken a look at DirectShow but it seems to be able to play from files only?

I am developing for Windows Mobile 6 Series

Answer (score 2):

You can try to save the mp3 as mp3 with RIFF-WAV header and embed the file in resources. I did not check windows-mobile and a file stored in resources but on Windows XP and separate file the PlaySound of such RIFF-WAV MP3 file works.

Comment: And on Windows 7 all the windows sounds are MP3 files embedded in WAV files.